# Why am I getting shift around header regions in two HTML pages built using almost same code

Tags: html, css

Below are two simple HTML pages. You will notice that the header of the pages move when one browse from one page to the next. I can not seem to figure out why the header does not remain on the same place...

http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/virgintest/landingPage.html
http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/virgintest/thankyoupage1.html

Below is a screenshot of what I mean. One can notice the 5/10 pixel shift around the header region in both the pages.

I will like to know from where that shift is happening and how to fix this. **Just to inform that these pages are responsive and built using Twitter BootStrap**

[image]

Comment: Which browser? Can't reproduce in Chrome or FF on Mac.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox on Windows

Comment: Sorry, can't test those :( *If* it's scrollbar related, the issue may not appear on Macs because the scrollbar 'floats' (doesn't take up viewport space).

Comment: I think it may have to do with scrollbar... oh well Windows. Definitely sure there has to be a solution.. Googling as we speak n;;;;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the header moves because you have a scrollbar on the second screen, so the width of the screen is smaller, and the site moves accordingly.

Comment: When I say it moves, if you read my question .., I mean horizontally as seen on the image . One can notice the 5/10 px difference in placement of the header as outlines by the lines.

Comment: Btw a solution will be nice :).. something other than overflow-x:hidden :)

Comment: I'd love to help out and provide a solution but I don't think there is one it's simply the way Windows handles browser viewport. You might want to try some JavaScript Scrollbar solution like http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ , but since I'm using a mac I cant really test out how it looks on Windows.